# <decimal constant> as a bare full stop

Tags: tex-core

On page 266 of the TeXbook, I find

```
<normal dimen> → <internal dimen> | <factor><unit of measure>
<factor> → <normal integer> | <decimal constant>
<decimal constant> → . 12 | , 12
| <digit><decimal constant>
| <decimal constant><digit>
```

(I can't do the subscript for "12" in a code block; assume it's there)

Doesn't this means that `.em` or `,en`, with no digits at all, are valid dimens? Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: `.₁₂` if you want subscripts

Comment: I guess you mean `em` in both instances, because `en` is not a valid unit of measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as you can easily check, `.pt` is a valid dimension equal to 0pt, as is `,em`.

Comment: I was going with `\dimen0=12pt \dimen0=,em \showthe\dimen0`, but yes ...